# $ \lim_{x \to \infty} x(\sqrt{2x^2+1}-x\sqrt{2})$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Any ideas fot evaluating:

$$ \lim_{x \to \infty} x(\sqrt{2x^2+1}-x\sqrt{2})$$

thanks.

Comment: First, multiply by $\displaystyle {\sqrt{2x^2+1}+x\sqrt 2\over\sqrt{2x^2+1}+x\sqrt 2}$.

Comment: tried, didn't help

Comment: So you wind up with $\displaystyle{x\over \sqrt {2x^2+1}+x\sqrt2}$. Now, divide top and bottom by $x$.

Comment: I wrote - instead +.. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While one way to proceed here is to write the term

$\sqrt{2x^2+1}-\sqrt{2}x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2x^2+1}+\sqrt{2}x}$

a second way is to write

$$\sqrt{2x^2+1}=\sqrt{2}x\left(1+\frac{1}{4x^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^4}\right)\right)$$

so that

$$\begin{align}
x\left(\sqrt{2x^2+1}-\sqrt{2}x\right)&=\sqrt{2}x^2\left(1+\frac{1}{4x^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^4}\right)\right)-\sqrt{2}x^2\\\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\\\\
&\to \frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:**

Multiply by

$$\frac{\sqrt{2x^2+1} + x\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{2x^2+1} + x\sqrt{2}}$$

to get

$$x(\sqrt{2x^2+1} - x\sqrt{2})\cdot \frac{\sqrt{2x^2+1} + x\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{2x^2+1} + x\sqrt{2}}= x\cdot \frac{x}{\sqrt{2x^2+1} + x\sqrt{2}}$$

At this point, you should see that the numerator has degree 1 and (in some sense) the denominator has degree 1 too (square root of a square), as David suggests on the comments, dividing by $x$ should gives you a light (L'Hopital should work too).

Comment: I was mistaken + as -. thanks

Answer (score 0):

After rationalization it become
$$=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x}{\sqrt{2x^2+1}+x\sqrt{2}}$$
Now you need to eliminate $x$ from nominator to define answer because function is undefined i.e. $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ after applying limit. Take common $x$ both from nominator and denominator
$$=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{{2}+\frac{1}{x^2}}+{\sqrt{2}}}$$
Now after applying limit it will become
$$=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2+0}+\sqrt{2}}$$
$$=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}$$